# Message-based games with ambiguous communication

Tags: gt.game-theory

Consider the following game. We are given two sets of sentences $S_1,S_2$ where $S_1$ is the set of "ambiguous sentences"
and $S_2$ is the set of "explicit sentences". Each ambiguous sentence $s \in S_1$ can be decoded to a set $\Delta(s) \subseteq S_2$. Suppose
furthermore that to each "explicit sentence" $s \in S_2$ is associated a cost $c(s)$, e.g. evaluating the cost of the action described by the sentence.

Now the game involves $n$ players $P_1,...,P_n$ that can communicate through a common network $N$. In each turn, a player $P_i$ can broadcast a sentence $s \in S_1$, and each other player $P_j$ can interpret it as some sentence $s_j \in \Delta(s)$. Suppose that the players are scored as follows: every time a player $P_i$ sends a sentence $s$ decoded into a set of sentences $s_j$, he is charged a score of $\sum_j c(s_j)$.

Suppose for simplicity that there are two types of players: the "honest players" that always choose a minimum-cost decoding, and the "devious players" that always choose a maximum-cost decoding. Is it possible to devise an approximate strategy for the honest players in order to minimize their total score?

Comment: We could also assume that there are different cost functions $c_1,\ldots,c_p$ corresponding to different criterions to optimize (deep, interesting, funny, etc...), and that each player is assigned a specific function $c_i$ corresponding to its mindset, and always tries to pick a decoding optimizing this cost. Consider an "affinity" function $A(P_i,P_j)$ that sums the scores awarded by player $P_j$ to the messages of $P_i$. For a given partition $K_1,...,K_q$ of the mindsets, is it possible to form a corresponding clustering in the affinity relation within a small number of steps?

Comment: Here is another possible approach for decoding: when player $P_j$ receives a message $s$ from $P_i$, he picks a decoding $d \in \Delta_j(s)$ according to a probability distribution (i.e. with prob. $p_j(d) = c_j(d) / \sum_{d' \in \Delta_j(s)} c_j(d')$), and then awards to $P_i$ the score $p_j(d)$. With this approach it seems possible to confuse adversary players by sending them messages that have many possible decodings w.r.t. their cost function (thus incurring a small score increase from this player).